# Where is the neutral hooked up to this old fuse box?

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image: Old fuse box that I'm talking about]I am wondering how the neutral is being fed back to the source? In new breaker box they usually have a neutral/ground bus. This does not

Comment: Can you measure the voltage between the two busbars on this panel please?

Answer (score 5):

### Neutral is being fed through fuses here

This panel is so old that it appears to have *fused neutrals* -- i.e. neutral is one of the fused/switched busbars in this panel, while the only hot is the other fused/switched busbar.  This is a highly obsolete and potentially hazardous configuration that has not been used in many decades, and makes this panel a prime candidate for total replacement.

Comment: OK, if that's the case then I'll have to replace the whole thing. Just out of curiosity, how is the neutral going back to the transformer? Sense there's only to hotwires coming into the fuse box. Also what fuse is the neutral connected to? Are these circuits Sharing one neutral?

Comment: Couldn't you just add a neutral bar, stop fusing neutrals, and get 4 more fuse spaces as a result? OP fusing neutral is bad because if neutral blows *and not hot*, you wind up with an energized neutral. Code requires hot(s) be tripped when neutral trips, which is possible with breakers but not fuses.

Comment: @JuddHeess -- one of the incoming wires is hot and the other is the neutral if my theory is correct

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- the OP's panel isn't even properly deadfront (see the main disconnect switch near the top), so keeping it in service is a "no go"

Comment: I’m not sure what “OP” stands for ?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel so does that mean that the incoming service is 120v ? from my understanding 240 v would need 2 hots and a neutral.

Comment: @JuddHeess OP = Original Poster (you, in this case).  The incoming service could very well be 120V, which is why I asked if you could measure the voltage between the two busbars

Comment: Okay let me measure that and get back to you ! Thanks

Comment: That wouldn't be a surprise. My winter cottage has 120V/30A service and a fuse box (now fed by a QO panel).  We've mulled EV charging here, would have to  level 1 and "very carefully" lol...

Comment: Yup it’s 125v/30A just like the main breaker says. Does this mean I'll also have to upgrade the service coming in if I want to 220?

Comment: @JuddHeess -- if this is the only panel, then yeah, you'd have to do a full service upgrade/"heavy up" to get 240V service